# text truncated using perl DBI insert

Tags: sql, perl, dbi, truncated

The problem is that `DBI`'s `insert` leaves long string truncated when inserting to MS SQL server. Here are my codes:

```
my $insert = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (field_1, field_2) values (?, ?)");
$insert->execute($value_1, $value_2);
```

where `field_2` has data type of `varchar(100)` and `$value_2` is a text string of 90 characters with spaces but no other special characters.

After the statement is executed, with no error raised, I checked the database and apparently the actual inserted `$value_2` is truncated at the **80th** character, which is in the middle of a regular English word (i.e. not a special character).

I've tried to alter the data type of `field_2` to `varchar(150)` and `text`. I've also used `$dbh->quote($value_2)` in place of `$value_2`. But they didn't help.

Why is this happening? What should I do? Thx!!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you've got RaiseError set on the connection? What platform is this? What DBD are you using and what driver under that?

Comment: Is the same string affected every time or does this happen no matter what string you enter.

Comment: What character encoding is your input data in? What character encoding does your database expect it to be in?

Comment: Affects all strings. Collations are the same and consistent across platforms. Turns out it was the freeTDS truncation problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using freeTDS it is probably a bug identified in the freeTDS mailing list. See [freetds silently truncating text/varchar/etc fields to 80 characters](http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/freetds/2011q2/026923.html) and http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/freetds/2011q2/026943.html and http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/freetds/2011q2/026925.html and http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/freetds/2011q2/026944.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd say try various strings to see if they all behave the same way.   It's probably an encoding issue as davorg suggests.  The default collation in MySQL is Swedish or Latin1 as I recall, so in MySQL you'll probably want to change your collation to utf8_general_ci.

Comment: All strings behave the same way. It was indeed the silent truncation problem as identified by @bohica.